# How to extract decimal number from string in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

```cs
string sentence = "X10 cats, Y20 dogs, 40 fish and 1 programmer.";
string[] digits = Regex.Split (sentence, @"\D+");
```

For this code I get these values in the digits array

> 10,20,40,1

```cs
string sentence = "X10.4 cats, Y20.5 dogs, 40 fish and 1 programmer.";
string[] digits = Regex.Split (sentence, @"\D+");
```

For this code I get these values in the digits array

> 10,4,20,5,40,1

But I would like to get like

> 10.4,20.5,40,1
> as decimal numbers. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I like how he used the very exact example of http://dotnetperls.com/regex-split

Comment: @Wildhorn - What's wrong with that? He probably discovered it while searching for an answer to his problem and noticed that it was close, but not quite close enough.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Small improvement to @Michael's solution:

```
// NOTES: about the LINQ:
// .Where() == filters the IEnumerable (which the array is)
//     (c=>...) is the lambda for dealing with each element of the array
//     where c is an array element.
// .Trim()  == trims all blank spaces at the start and end of the string
var doubleArray = Regex.Split(sentence, @"[^0-9\.]+")
    .Where(c => c != "." && c.Trim() != "");
```

Returns:

```
10.4
20.5
40
1
```

The original solution was returning

```
[empty line here]
10.4
20.5
40
1
.
```

Comment: .Where (w => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(w)) is more elegant. (>= .net 4)

Comment: @kami: that's because the regex expression was looking only for positive numbers. You'd have to modify the regex for your situation. However, my answer was specifically (7 years ago) aimed at solving the OP, and not meant for all situations.

Answer (score 11):

The **decimal/float number extraction regex** can be different depending on whether and what thousand separators are used, what symbol denotes a decimal separator, whether one wants to also match an exponent, whether or not to match a positive or negative sign, whether or not to match numbers that may have leading `0` omitted, whether or not extract a number that ends with a decimal separator.

A **generic regex to match the most common decimal number types** is provided in [*Matching Floating Point Numbers with a Regular Expression*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html):

```
[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
```

I only changed the capturing group to a non-capturing one (added `?:` after `(`). [It matches](https://regex101.com/r/L5oADP/1) [image]

If you need to make it even more generic, **if the decimal separator can be either a dot or a comma**, replace `\.` with a character class (or a bracket expression) `[.,]`:

```
[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
           ^^^^
```

Note *the expressions above match both integer and floats*. **To match only float/decimal numbers** make sure the fractional pattern part is obligatory by removing the second `?` after `\.` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/L5oADP/2)):

```
[-+]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
            ^
```

Now, `34` is not matched: [image] is matched.

**If you do not want to match float numbers without leading zeros (like `.5`)** make the first digit matching pattern obligatory (by adding `+` quantifier, to match 1 or more occurrences of digits):

```
[-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
          ^
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/L5oADP/3). Now, it matches much fewer samples:
[image]

Now, what if you do not want to match `<digits>.<digits>` inside `<digits>.<digits>.<digits>.<digits>`? How to match them **as whole words**? Use *lookarounds*:

```
[-+]?(?<!\d\.)\b[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?\b(?!\.\d)
```

And a [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/L5oADP/4):

[image]

Now, what about those floats that have thousand separators, like `12 123 456.23` or `34,345,767.678`? You may add `(?:[,\s][0-9]+)*` after the first `[0-9]+` to match zero or more sequences of a comma or whitespace followed with 1+ digits:

```
[-+]?(?<![0-9]\.)\b[0-9]+(?:[,\s][0-9]+)*\.[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?\b(?!\.[0-9])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L5oADP/5):

[image]

Swap a comma with `\.` if you need to use a comma as a decimal separator and a period as as thousand separator.

**Now, how to use these patterns in C#?**

```
var results = Regex.Matches(input, @"<PATTERN_HERE>")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This would not work for strings like "1,000,000.20" or "1.000.000,20".

Comment: @joanfihu It [works for `1,000,000.20`, but certainly not for `1.000.000,20`](https://regex101.com/r/YFGJAe/1) as these should not be used in one and the same context since the second one does not follow the US number format. You need to manually change the expression to use periods as digit grouping symbols and commas as decimal separator.

Comment: Thank you. The first example does work with the last regex. I used the one that works with commas and points.What would you use to detect number formatting? I need it to work in US and UK formatting and rest of the world.

Comment: @joanfihu Try ORing it all - [see this demo](https://regex101.com/r/yASoeo/1). Note that in case you do not have to match numbers in close succession, i.e. if your texts are clean and numbers  are not following each other (after a comma or dot), it may be much easier, say, something like [`\d[\d.,]*(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/wUPLoo/1). Enclose with word boundaries if necessary.

Answer (score 6):

try

```
Regex.Split (sentence, @"[^0-9\.]+")
```

Comment: This would also give you a false positive on a value of 10.1.1.4.

Comment: Doesn't the caret (^) negate this?

Comment: @Daren Thomas, \D equal [^0-9]

Comment: @Joel Etherton, yes, it will match also string like '10.1.1.4' and even single dot.

Comment: @Daren Thomas, You're *splitting* the sentence at a series of non-numeric characters, leaving only numerics behind.

Comment: @strager, yeah, I figured that out too. I guess I still think in Regex matches as opposed to splitting on them...

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to allow for decimal places in your regular expression. Try the following:

```
\d+(\.\d+)?
```

This will match the numbers rather than everything other than the numbers, but it should be simple to iterate through the matches to build your array.

Something to keep in mind is whether you should also be looking for negative signs, commas, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check the syntax lexers for most programming languages for a regex for decimals.
Match that regex to the string, finding all matches.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Linq:

```
stringArray.Select(s=>decimal.Parse(s));
```

A `foreach` would also work. You may need to check that each `string` is actually a number (`.Parse` does not throw en exception).

Comment: s is the in-scope variable for the Linq query. It is similar to saying foreach(string s in stringArray).

Answer (score 0):

Credit for following goes to @code4life. All I added is a for loop for parsing the integers/decimals before returning.

```
    public string[] ExtractNumbersFromString(string input)
    {
        input = input.Replace(",", string.Empty);

        var numbers =  Regex.Split(input, @"[^0-9\.]+").Where(c => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(c) && c != ".").ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            numbers[i] = decimal.Parse(numbers[i]).ToString();

        return numbers;
    }
```