# Extract specific text from a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

This is the string: "-random text- $0.15 USD"

What I want to extract is the "0.15" behind, excluding the $ and USD. So the text will only contain "0.15" with all other words gone.

How do I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That depends on whether there's periods and digits in the random text. But the text behind the `0.15`, is that fixed?

Comment: @xanatos That would be too easy. `return "0.15";` I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575331/how-do-extract-decimal-number-from-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @MrLister It's quite clear what he wants, and it's quite clear that he hasn't spent too much time describing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using regexes

```
string str = "-random text- $0.15 USD";

Regex rx = new Regex(@"(?<=\$)[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(?= USD$)");
var res = rx.Match(str);

if (res.Success) {
    var res2 = res.ToString();
}
```

The "main" part is `[0-9]+\.[0-9]+` (one or more digits followed by a `.` followed by one or more digits). This expression must follow a `$` sign `(?<=\$)` and must be followed by `USD` (there is a space before `USD`) plus end of string `(?= USD$)`.

Online test: http://regexr.com?30aot

Comment: This works well, thanks!

edit: I have another problem, assuming that I'll have alot of strings copied in a rich text box, and how do get only the "0.15" inside them? Note that the "0.15" is not a fixed value.

And thanks all of you for the input, appreciate it. I'm quite new to strings, I've looked at regex but have no idea how to use it :/

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = Regex.Match("-random text- $0.15 USD",   @"\$([ \d\.]+)USD")
                  .Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex. Something like:

```
\d+\.*\d+
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are your friend here.

Use the `RegEx` class (`System.Text.RegularExpressions`), using a pattern of `([\d\.]+)` to extract the number + decimal place.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
    string str = "-random text- $0.15 USD";
    int startIndex = str.IndexOf("$")+1;
    int length = str.IndexOf("USD", startIndex) - startIndex;
    string output = str.Substring(startIndex, length).Trim();
```

Comment: could be but for that I do a find for USD after the $ sign here- str.IndexOf("USD", startIndex) but this code needs additional checking for length.

Comment: This will break if the random text contains a `$` sign.

Answer (score 1):

Why use regexes when you can use the built-in `String` methods?

```
 int startIndex = myRandomString.LastIndexOf("$") + 1;
 int lastIndex = myRandomString.LastIndexOf("U") - startIndex;

 string price = random.Substring(startIndex, lastIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string sentence = "-random text- $0.15 USD";
string[] doubleArray = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(sentence, @"[^0-9\.]+")
                       .Where(c => c != "." && c.Trim() != "").ToArray();
if (doubleArray.Count() > 0)
{
     double value = double.Parse(doubleArray[0]);
}

output:
.15
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using [regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx)?

`Regex.Match("0.15");`

Comment: If `0.15` is fixed. Else, there are other great answers on here you can take from.

Comment: Because of your anchors it would find the "0.15" not in the example string.

Comment: -1 its a bad question where no effort has been put in, but this is obviously not what was asked.