# Get decimal value from string using regex C#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to extract *decimal value* of input string

`Total (pre tax) 93.78 EUR`

I tried with

```
Regex.Replace(string input, "[^0-9]+", string.Empty)
```

but it only extracted `9370` where the expected outcome is `93.78`.

Kindly help me with the pattern to *get decimal value*.

Comment: Try with [0-9]*\.?[0-9]+

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do extract decimal number from string in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575331/how-do-extract-decimal-number-from-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: try `Regex.Replace(string input, "[^\d\.]", string.Empty)`, if the decimal possibly to be negative value, try `Regex.Replace(string input, "[^\d\.-]", string.Empty)`

Comment: As Dmitry Bychenko noted in his answer... why are you removing everything you don't need instead of simply matching the piece you _do_ need?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest *matching* instead of *replacing*: let's *extract* the value of interest, instead of *deleting* all the other characters.

```
string result = Regex.Match(
     "Total (pre tax) 93.78 EUR", 
    @"[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?")
  .Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're currently replacing everything that isn't a digit - and that includes `.`.

I would suggest instead that you capture groups of digits with optional "dot followed by more digits". That way you'll be able to capture more than one value from text as well - or reject it if you need to, based on whatever criteria you have. Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()        
    {
        string text = "I start with 5 and take away 2.52 to get 2.48 as a result";
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+(\.\d+)?");
        var matches = regex.Matches(text);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
5
2.52
2.48
```

You can use `MatchCollection.Count` to determine how many matches there are - we don't know your context, but you may well want to take different actions depending on whether there are no matches, exactly one match, or more than one match.

Answer (score 1):

For integer or float:

```
string result = Regex.Match(input,@"[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?").Value;
```

for only floats:

```
string result = Regex.Match(input,@"[0-9]+\.[0-9]+").Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use your approach as a quick hack if you add `'.'` to the list of characters that you wish to keep, i.e. `[^0-9.]`. However, this would not be robust enough, because it would keep other digits, e.g.

```
Total (inclusive of 20% VAT) 93.78 EUR
```

would yield `2093.78`, which is not what you are looking for.

A better approach is to use a regex that is specific for the price, for example

```
@"(\d+[.,]\d\d) EUR"
```

would match a number with two decimal digits, when it is followed by `EUR`.

Answer (score 0):

`Regex.Split()` will extract all floating values from input string and stores it into `string[]`, as simple as `string.Split` function

you can try with this:

```
string stringInput = "Total (pre tax) 93.78 EUR";
string[] splitValue = Regex.Split (stringInput , @"[^0-9\.]+");
foreach(string item in splitValue)
{
    //Here you can convert it to decimal
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Output:

```
93.78
```

[DotnetFiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mvK26T)

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "Java JDK 12.0.1";
var result = Regex.Matches(input, @"[0-9]+(\.[0-9]\.[0-9]+)?");
```

> result: 12.0.1